# Вызов родительского конструктора перемещения

Tags: c++

Имеется базовый класс и класс - наследник. Как известно, я могу вызвать родительский конструктор, записав его в списке инициализации конструктора класса - наследника:

```
class TestCopy1
{
public:
    TestCopy1(const TestCopy1 & t){}
};

class TestCopy2: public TestCopy1
{
public:
    TestCopy2(const TestCopy2 & t):TestCopy1(t) {}
};
```

Такая запись прекрасно работает, и я достигаю нужного функционала. Но как вызвать родительский конструктор *перемещения*? Возможно ли? Или следует полностью переопределять его в наследнике? Такая запись не работает, конструктор пытается вызвать именно конструктор копирования, который не определён:

```
class TestMove1
{
public:
    TestMove1(TestMove1 && t) {}
};

class TestMove2 : public TestMove1
{
public:
    TestMove2(TestMove2 && t) :TestMove1(t) {}
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну так подскажите компилятору, что вы от него хотите

```
TestMove2(TestMove2 && t) :TestMove1(std::move(t)) {}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!